# Помогите разобраться в BufferedReader

Tags: java

Хочется разобраться (в сути) в классе `BufferedReader.read();`

Вот программа :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       int S_taj = 17, mass_tela;
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "Cp1251"));

        System.out.println("Введите массу тела: ");
        mass_tela = bf.read();
        float resoult = (mass_tela * S_taj)/100;
        System.out.println("На луне, ваша масса будет равна: " + resoult + " кг");
    }
}
```

Как бы все логично, Но, когда ввожу массу тела (100), то записывается 49 а не 100.

Читал мануал, там написано, что `BufferedReader.read();` считывает Reads a single character при том int. Конечно, можно использовать Scaner, но хочу понять суть вещей, что к чему.

Answer (score 1):

bf.read() считывает по симвалам. у нас из 100 будет считывать только 1. А 1 в ACSII представляется под 49 номером.

Вам надо [readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) вызывать, который всю строку прочтет и вернет String со значением 100.

```
    int S_taj = 17, mass_tela;
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "Cp1251"));

    System.out.println("Введите массу тела: ");
    mass_tela = Integer.valueOf(bf.readLine());
    float resoult = (mass_tela * S_taj)/100;
    System.out.println("На луне, ваша масса будет равна: " + resoult + " кг");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Да ридлайн я вкурсе. Но не хотелось конвертить в инт. Хочу разобраться как писать программы эффективно. Что бы кода было поменьше... В общем оптимизировать.

Comment: @ToysUnderway всегда пожалуйста. если данный ответ помог вам решить проблему, вы всегда можете поблагодарить и выбрать его как правильный, нажав на зеленую  галочку около ответа

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в этом случае не конвертировать не получится так как оператор read возвращает 
кодировку а нам нужен int или float
The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached